# Azure Webjobs SDK - Can I create a binding/trigger on Azure Data Lake Store File

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-data-lake

The requirements is to monitor an ADLS directory for any new files created. If so create a trigger which can be captured and actioned as applicable.

I have noticed the core Webjobs SDK provide Trigger : BlobTrigger and Binding : Blob.

I was wondering if there is any implementation out of the box or should be  coded ? If this is something which needs to be coded can you help me with a code sample or links which could be of help ?

Answer (score 1):

This capability does not exist today. Please enter a uservoice item to officially have the feature request logged here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites

Comment: We were planning to write our own file watcher anyhow considering the effort we have decided to use to the QueueWatcher for this purpose. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Webjob extensions SDK allows you to create your own bindings :

- [Binding Extensions Overview](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/Binding-Extensions-Overview)